# libs suddenly won't load in dynamic linker (NDK)

Tags: android, c++, gcc, g++, android-ndk

I've been developing an NDK app for quite some time and it's been working well. However, today the app randomly decided to not start anymore, after I compiled it after making some nominal change. It's caused by a cryptic problem with loading the app's main library. Here's some log output:

```
08-11 18:38:11.220 D/dalvikvm( 1237): Added shared lib /mnt/asec/com.audia.rta-1/lib/libqtandroid.so 0x40513bd8
08-11 18:38:11.220 D/dalvikvm( 1237): No JNI_OnLoad found in /mnt/asec/com.audia.rta-1/lib/libqtandroid.so 0x40513bd8, skipping init
08-11 18:38:11.220 D/dalvikvm( 1237): Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.audia.rta-1/lib/librta.so 0x40513bd8
08-11 18:38:11.260 D/AndroidRuntime( 1237): Shutting down VM
08-11 18:38:11.260 W/dalvikvm( 1237): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-11 18:38:11.260 E/AndroidRuntime( 1237): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 18:38:11.260 E/AndroidRuntime( 1237): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1311]:    67 cannot locate '_ZNSaIcEC1Ev'...
08-11 18:38:11.260 E/AndroidRuntime( 1237): 
08-11 18:38:11.260 E/AndroidRuntime( 1237):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:434)
08-11 18:38:11.260 E/AndroidRuntime( 1237):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
08-11 18:38:11.260 E/AndroidRuntime( 1237):     at com.audia.rta.RTA.onCreate(RTA.java:139)
```

According to some Google results, `_ZNSaIcEC1Ev` is part of `libstdc++`. I've checked, and it gets linked in the build process, and `g++` is being used for linking.

Oddly enough, reverting to an older apk of the app fixes the problem, but *compiling* an old revision and installing that doesn't fix the problem. Everything in my build system is checked into version control, and I've done several clean builds. All my builds were working today and then they just stopped working. I didn't upgrade or install anything; it happened while I was in the middle of testing new code. What happened?

**Update:** Building from a freshly checked out copy doesn't fix the problem.

**Update 2:** Is there any way I can track down the link to that symbol, maybe with `objdump`? Maybe this could provide some clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up compiling everything with a fresh NDK install, and it worked. It's as if the old one was corrupted somehow, though I have no idea how.

It was also an upgrade from `r5b` to `r6`, so maybe it's related to the NDK version.